# How to get address of Delphi code label in another function?

Tags: delphi, assembly, delphi-5, delphi-xe7

I am trying to migrate some code from Delphi 5 to Delphi XE7-WIN64.
The scenario is latest Delphi doesn't allow mixed assembly and Delphi code.
Also I am asm newbie.

Original Code:

```
function TclDbgHelpStackTracer.GetSymbolSearchPath(): string;
var
  sPath: array[0..MAX_PATH] of char;
  mbi: MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION;
  pProc: Pointer;
label l1;
begin
  asm
    mov eax, offset l1
    mov pProc, eax
  end;
l1:
  Result := '';
  if (GetEnvironmentVariable(SYMBOL_PATH) <> '') then
Result := GetEnvironmentVariable(SYMBOL_PATH) + ';';
  if (GetEnvironmentVariable(ALTERNATE_SYMBOL_PATH) <> '') then
    Result := Result + GetEnvironmentVariable(ALTERNATE_SYMBOL_PATH) + ';';
  if (GetEnvironmentVariable('SystemRoot') <> '') then
    Result := Result + GetEnvironmentVariable('SystemRoot') + ';';

VirtualQuery(pProc, mbi, sizeof(mbi));
GetModuleFileName(Cardinal(mbi.AllocationBase), sPath, MAX_PATH);
StrRScan(sPath, '\')^ := #0;
Result := Result + sPath + ';';

GetModuleFileName(0, sPath, MAX_PATH);
StrRScan(sPath, '\')^ := #0;
Result := Result + sPath;
end;
```

The above code works in Delphi XE7-WIN32
But as you can see the above snippet has nested asm block
Delphi XE7-WIN64 requires procedures/functions to only contain asm or pascal code.
So I changed it to following:

```
{$IFDEF WIN64}
procedure AsmProc(pProc: Pointer);
asm
mov eax, offset l1
mov pProc, eax
end;
{$ENDIF}

function TclDbgHelpStackTracer.GetSymbolSearchPath(): string;
var
  sPath: array[0..MAX_PATH] of char;
  mbi: MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION;
  pProc: Pointer;
label l1;
begin
{$IFDEF WIN32}
  asm
    mov eax, offset l1
    mov pProc, eax
  end;
{$ELSE}
    AsmProc(pProc);
{$ENDIF}
l1:
  Result := '';
  if (GetEnvironmentVariable(SYMBOL_PATH) <> '') then
                Result := GetEnvironmentVariable(SYMBOL_PATH) + ';';
  if (GetEnvironmentVariable(ALTERNATE_SYMBOL_PATH) <> '') then
                Result := Result + GetEnvironmentVariable(ALTERNATE_SYMBOL_PATH) + ';';
  if (GetEnvironmentVariable('SystemRoot') <> '') then
                Result := Result + GetEnvironmentVariable('SystemRoot') + ';';

  VirtualQuery(pProc, mbi, sizeof(mbi));
  GetModuleFileName(Cardinal(mbi.AllocationBase), sPath, MAX_PATH);
  StrRScan(sPath, '\')^ := #0;
  Result := Result + sPath + ';';

  GetModuleFileName(0, sPath, MAX_PATH);
  StrRScan(sPath, '\')^ := #0;
  Result := Result + sPath;
end;
```

Now here the trouble starts.
l1 is code label, its address (address of next executable statement) is moved to eax
then pointer pProc is made to point along this address.
and then pointer pProc is used in

```
  VirtualQuery(pProc, mbi, sizeof(mbi));
```

Question Is How to pass address of l1? Or is there any other method to do the same?

Comment: Enlightenment will be reached by removing the asm. It will also help to start checking for errors and to stop truncating pointers. Before you progress in the 64 bit world you have to recognise that pointers are 64 bits wide.

Comment: As @rob-kennedy commented under my (now deleted) answer, you can achieve the same by using the global `HInstance` variable instead of the `Cardinal(mbi.AllocationBase)` and throw the `pProc` and the assembly code away

Comment: @xmojmr I did'nt delete your answer.  :( I am going to try the fix on monday as I am OOO.

Comment: And It seems I also lost @rob-kennedy 's comment.

Comment: I deleted the answer myself as it was only partially useful. This is the Rob's comment: "This code calls `VirtualQuery` to get the base memory address. It _assumes_ that it will be the base address of the whole DLL, and it further _assumes_ that the base address can stand in for a module handle. It passes that "handle" to `GetModuleFileName` to get the name of the DLL. But the DLL already has a handle to itself in the global `HInstance` variable. There was never any need to call `VirtualQuery` at all."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the question makes a real meal of extracting the name of the module that contains the executing code. All you need is this:

```
function TclDbgHelpStackTracer.GetSymbolSearchPath(): string;

  function GetEnvPath(const Name: string): string;
  var
    Value: string;
  begin
    Value := GetEnvironmentVariable(Name);
    if Value <> '' then
      Result := Value + ';'
    else
      Result := '';
  end;

  function GetModulePath(Module: HMODULE): string;
  begin
    Result := ExtractFileDir(GetModuleName(Module));
  end;

begin
  Result :=
    GetEnvPath(SYMBOL_PATH) +
    GetEnvPath(ALTERNATE_SYMBOL_PATH) +
    GetEnvPath('SystemRoot') +
    GetModulePath(HInstance) + ';' +
    GetModulePath(0);
end;
```

The `asm` code in your question was, frankly, bizarre. There's just no need to do it that way. All the code was attempting to do was find the module handle which is already available as the global `HInstance` variable.

As a general rule, you should try to avoid using `asm`. It makes code less portable and harder to understand. There are times when using `asm` is the right choice. This is not one of those occasions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems perfect. Will check and accept it as answer on Monday.